# feature_importances_ when using random forests in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using Random forests in scikit-learn. I used feature_importances_ to see how much each feature is important in prediction goal. But I don't understand what is this score. Googling feature_importances_ says it is the mean decrease impurity. But I'm still confused whether this is the same as mean decrease gigi impurity. If so, how it is calculated for trees and random forests? Beside the math I want to really understand what does it mean.

Comment: Could someone help, please ?

Comment: The short answer would be: `feature_importances_` gives you an insight of which features have been more critical to correctly split the data at a given node. In other words, a higer score would mean *more useful* feature, which *better splits* the data. If a feature has a very low score you could potentially remove it. However, large amount of features (proportional to the number of trees) would be desirable since this would allow to grow very different trees (uncorrelated) that will yield more generalized classifier/regressor.

Comment: Find a couple of slides [here](http://media.wix.com/ugd/6d8e3a_e177ceb85691420f88775c05c4be27f3.pdf) (14 and 15) talking *not mathematicaly* about it.

Answer (score 1):

feature_importances_ function will tell you how much each feature is contributing towards prediction (Information gain)

Random forest classify the independent variables or features based on Gini, Information Gain, Chi-square or entropy. Those features will get high score which contribute maximum to the information gain.